# How to prevent sleep/keep screen on when on USB power for Ubuntu Touch devices?

Tags: usb, ubuntu-touch, suspend, power-management

On Android devices, there is an option [Settings > Developer Options > Stay awake when charging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840954/how-do-i-keep-my-screen-unlocked-during-usb-debugging) which keeps the device ON (prevents sleep) even if the device is not touched, when the device is connected via USB and is charging.

Is there something similar for Ubuntu Touch OS devices?

Comment: I think there is no such option present right now. You might want to report a bug (feature request) for this. As a workaround you may use this Active Screen app by Michal Predotka: https://uappexplorer.com/app/activescreen.mivoligo

Comment: Many thanks for that, @pomsky - great to know that!

Comment: Or you could set the 'lock when idle' time in the battery settings to 'never'.

Comment: Filled a bug/feature request here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-ui-toolkit/+bug/1580479

Comment: @eDeviser That did the trick, great workaround.. thanks.